# Microsoft Report Viewer Version 11

Tags: c#, report, version, viewer

I am creating Microsoft Report Viewer Version 11, Works well locally, but when upload to the server I find the below error.

Report Viewer Configuration Error

The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file. Add  to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add  to the system.webServer/handlers section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.

this is my web.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
        validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      </assemblies>
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
      </buildProviders>
    </compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
    <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I am Waiting for your help 

Thank you

Comment: I try with Version 10, but get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration settings is incorrect. The "name" attribute is missing the handler section. Use this instead.

```
<add name="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
```